# Generation of All Path in a Directed Acyclic Graph

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, algorithms

I am working on a very large dataset of a single [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) whose vertices have a low branching factor. I need to generate all possible (simple) paths starting from the source and write them to a file.

My question is: what is [computational complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory) class of this problem?

If this problem is [NP-Hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard), is there any relatively space-efficient algorithm that can generate this exponential number of paths iteratively?

*Any references are extremely appreciated.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The worst case is exponential in the number of nodes. Consider a Binary Decision Diagram (BDD) which is a DAG with outdegrees 2. Let it be on $n$ boolean variables and on $m$ nodes. Each assignment of the variables corresponds to a path to either True or False, so there are at least $2^n$ simple paths. Even if iterating a path is O(1), you will have to do it $2^n$ times (not counting the inner paths). You may be lucky with your specific case though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The worst case is exponential in the number of nodes. Consider an [Ordered Binary Decision Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram) (OBDD) which is a DAG with outdegrees 2. Let it be on $n$ boolean variables and on $m$ nodes. Each assignment of the variables corresponds to a path to either True or False, so there are at least $2^n$ (simple) paths. Even if outputting a path is $O(1)$, you will have to do it $2^n$ times (not counting the inner paths).

To check if you are lucky, you can efficiently count the number of paths via powers of the [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix).

The open source software [sage](http://sagemath.org) (available online at http://sagenb.org/)
has a method "all_simple_paths()" that does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the OBDD example, I think there is no way to solve this problem but falling back to a naive brute-force attack since the enumeration of all possible paths is a goal not a side-effect.
Considering a space-efficient algorithm I can think of an implementation where bit-vectors are used to represent paths for example.
I will take a look at sage's method, thanks a lot. 